# Word VBA: Accessing clicked ActiveX Checkbox

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-office

I have multiple ActiveX checkboxes in my document in a table. They're all calling the same function.

With `Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex` and `Selection.Cells(1).ColumnIndex` I can find out the table cell of the checkbox.

Is it possible that I can get the value of the clicked checkbox aswell?
I could only find this code: `ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Value`. But this code is referencing an individual checkbox.

I need to reference the checkbox that was just clicked.

Is that possible and if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Dim c As Cell
Set c = Selection.Cells(1)
Debug.Print c.Range.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Value
```